# Ruby Sinatra: Can I update a view template multiple times within one client request

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I want to do this:

```
get '/test' do
    @dog = 'WOOF'
    erb :test
    sleep(1)
    @dog = 'BOWWOW'
    erb :test
    sleep(1)
    @dog = 'ARF'
    erb :test
  end
```

Is it possible to do something like this where the client sees each update or no, I've tried but can't get it to work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Andrew Marshall I'm trying to render the view several times within one get request. The practical purpose is in a checkers game I'm building where I need to develop a way for a single player mode to process a player's move request and then process the AI's move before the end of the request. What I would like to do is show the view after the player's move, process the AI's move, and then render the view again. The thing is my code depends on client requests to move the game along. I'm somewhat sure the AI can't generate a request itself, so the game flow gets stuck. Sorry for the long respons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: **no**.

I think you're confusing the way HTTP works. First, HTTP is [stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_server). This means that multiple requests know nothing about each other (this is mitigated by the use of sessions via cookies, or possibly HTTP basic auth).

Further, you cannot resend the HTTP body like you're doing. Once it's sent there's no going back. Techniques like long-polling delay sending the body so they can send it whenever they like, but once they send something the request is complete and a new one must be started. Thus, once you've rendered the body once via `erb`, you're request is finished.

What it seems like you're trying to achieve can only be done via Javascript with [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), or with completely separate full-page requests.